# setup format for columns of DataTable or GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I setup some format for cells in some column in my DataTable or GridView ?

I need to make some double columns rounded , for example :

3.564643 -> 3.56

3.546723 -> 3.55

6.654644 -> 6.65

thank you.

DataFormatString  ?
where ?

Question still active, I didn't solved the problem :-/

Answer (score 2):

For some samples on how to use string formatting, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx). It sound like you want to use:

`DataTextFormatString="{0:N2}"`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this MSDN article: [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Formatting the GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx).

On the GridView select Edit Columns -> select desired column -> select `ItemStyle` property from the right pane -> set the `DataFormatString` to `{0:N2}`.

The linked article has screenshots and an explanation to point you in the right direction. Also refer to the [DataFormatString page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) for formatting information.

Comment: But I've got dynamic rows ... So still can't find this property ... :-/
there is GridView.Columns[0].ItemStyle. and then ???

Comment: @nCdy: this should be found on the designer page. How are you binding your data? Can you define the columns in the GridView from the designer then bind to them?

Comment: no I can't ... I bind data taking DataTable from object data source and all my columns is dynamic